# Illegal string offset 'url' Wordpress

Tags: php

Receiving the following error , Warning: Illegal string offset 'url'. Not sure how to fix this? Any help would be great.

```
<div class="product-box">

                                                <div class="product-logo-box">
                                                  <div class="product-logo">
                                   <img src="<?php echo $c_icon ['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $c_name; ?>" title="<?php echo $c_name; ?>">
</div>
                                                    <div class="logo-text">
                                                        <div>
                                                            <h4><?php echo $c_name; ?></h4>
                                                            <?php if( !empty( $c_snam ) ){ ?>
                                                                <span><?php echo $c_snam; ?></span>
                                                            <?php } ?>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

Comment: That means that you're trying to offset into a string that is not an array. If `$c_icon` is an array, maybe it was overwritten somewhere along the way. Not enough detail here to know.

Comment: Did you write this code or get it from somewhere? Did it ever work? Looks like `$c_icon` isn't populated as needed. And there is no code here showing where that data comes from.

Comment: It was already written from our website creator. It was working fine to a few months ago and now the images arnt showing on our website.

Comment: Is there more code i can provide you with?

Comment: Please use some code formatting here.